# Docker RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt Vs multiple RUN pip3 install?

Tags: python, django, docker

I am using a Dockerfile in which I do :

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

In order to fasten the build phase I wanted to replace that by a succesion of

```
RUN pip3 install library_xxx
```

I can't figure out why, but this second way of installing doesn't produce any error in the build time, but then when launching django, django complains about not finding some libraries. Coming back to a `install -r` solve the issue.

Any clue why these two different type of install could differ ?

Here is the requirements.txt :

```
django==3.1.2
Pillow==7.0.0
python-docx==0.8.10
django-crispy-forms==1.9.2
djangorestframework==3.12.2
python-barcode==0.13.1
uwsgi==2.0.19.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
requests==2.22.0
pygraphviz==1.6.0
django-extensions==3.1.0
pafy
django-colorfield
django-debug-toolbar
django-cors-headers
factory_boy
```

Comment: Running multiple `pip install` commands is almost guaranteed to be slower than a single call to `pip install` (because you're forcing `pip` to recalculate dependencies multiple times). Besides, if your `requirements.txt` isn't changing, that build step should be instantaneous due to caching after the first build.

Comment: How would you keep this list of individually-installed packages in sync with the package list in the virtual environment you normally use for development?

Comment: @larsks : I am unaware that docker would cache the requirement's contents ?  I thought that has beeing a text file it would re-calculate at each build (which I have to say I still think it does... this is why I wanted to put the requirements in hard-coded way in the dockerfile... Maybe I am wrong ! ) but this don't explain why the fact to hard-code the librairy list would imply a distinct behaviour afterwhat .... Or does it ? The re-calculation of the dependencies could change the installation output ?

Comment: @DavidMaze : I have to say this is a secondary question in this context, but to answer it, I was thinking in a 'sed' command prior the build to replace the "install -r" by the content of the "requirements.txt".

Comment: If `docker build` has cached the image build up to this point, the `COPY requirements.txt ./` line will check to see if the contents of the requirements file have changed, and if not, the `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` will also use the cache.